# NEAR transaction without receipt but with receipt_outcome

Tags: nearprotocol, near

When querying [archival node](https://archival-rpc.mainnet.near.org) for transactions with `EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status` method, some transactions have no `receipts` while having `receipts_outcome`. How is that possible, and how is that transaction different from others?

If I understand correctly, `receipts_outcome` are the results of applying `receipts`. According to [explorer](https://explorer.near.org/transactions/7beNxrbHxMRspJWT9NeEVwx719kVcmY9tRdPG9SYro26), this transaction has `Convert Transaction To Receipt` part, so there should be some receipts generated.

According to [documentation](https://docs.near.org/docs/concepts/transaction#transaction-processing)

> A Receipt is the only actionable object in the system. When we talk about "processing a transaction" on the NEAR platform, this eventually means "applying receipts" at some point.

> A good mental model is to think of a Receipt as a paid message to be executed at the destination (receiver). And a Transaction is an externally issued request to create the Receipt (there is a 1 to 1 relationship).

My query

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "2",
  "method": "EXPERIMENTAL_tx_status",
  "params": ["7beNxrbHxMRspJWT9NeEVwx719kVcmY9tRdPG9SYro26", "bumbleee99.near"]
}
```

Response

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "result": {
        "status": {
            "SuccessValue": ""
        },
        "transaction": {
            "signer_id": "bumbleee99.near",
            "public_key": "ed25519:DFM5GRGbpNkk4XkhcFnRUFeKG8a3nzTH8NwZp754pC48",
            "nonce": 59080995000003,
            "receiver_id": "bumbleee99.near",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "AddKey": {
                        "public_key": "ed25519:CUoNs153GHrPZ9F8HpvhzFr1mwuUFUdGQsRNE2CTNjVH",
                        "access_key": {
                            "nonce": 0,
                            "permission": "FullAccess"
                        }
                    }
                }
            ],
            "signature": "ed25519:15v34qoyCHSvSL5uLcaPqD9vXvjcPrCaZVStCMms8e58C62z2UHiazwUXzHajPEgdHpwn7s4J9dd5UPmtvzbYgM",
            "hash": "7beNxrbHxMRspJWT9NeEVwx719kVcmY9tRdPG9SYro26"
        },
        "transaction_outcome": {
            "proof": [
                {
                    "hash": "ECKDm5FVhzit7Wqs9sEyBB9NtuTrVRZmWwcxkkg2yUh4",
                    "direction": "Right"
                },
                {
                    "hash": "E4VXdwsNj3fZCbP6y9YH3M5oZHPDcdArqU9kbZJa95Qp",
                    "direction": "Right"
                }
            ],
            "block_hash": "ASY6HgDUQUXUa99L7dPEfghKEnEk5SNkwQrx24u3Fobz",
            "id": "7beNxrbHxMRspJWT9NeEVwx719kVcmY9tRdPG9SYro26",
            "outcome": {
                "logs": [],
                "receipt_ids": [
                    "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
                ],
                "gas_burnt": 209824625000,
                "tokens_burnt": "20982462500000000000",
                "executor_id": "bumbleee99.near",
                "status": {
                    "SuccessReceiptId": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
                },
                "metadata": {
                    "version": 1,
                    "gas_profile": null
                }
            }
        },
        "receipts_outcome": [
            {
                "proof": [
                    {
                        "hash": "8RwCWE9HgqenPKv8JW9eg2iSLMaQW82wvebYSfjPbdTY",
                        "direction": "Left"
                    },
                    {
                        "hash": "E4VXdwsNj3fZCbP6y9YH3M5oZHPDcdArqU9kbZJa95Qp",
                        "direction": "Right"
                    }
                ],
                "block_hash": "ASY6HgDUQUXUa99L7dPEfghKEnEk5SNkwQrx24u3Fobz",
                "id": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ",
                "outcome": {
                    "logs": [],
                    "receipt_ids": [],
                    "gas_burnt": 209824625000,
                    "tokens_burnt": "20982462500000000000",
                    "executor_id": "bumbleee99.near",
                    "status": {
                        "SuccessValue": ""
                    },
                    "metadata": {
                        "version": 1,
                        "gas_profile": []
                    }
                }
            }
        ],
        "receipts": []
    },
    "id": "2"
}
```

You could see that both `transaction_outcome.outcome.receipt_ids` and `transaction_outcome.outcome.status` are pointing to a receipt with ID `JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ`.  I've tried querying node about this receipt with `EXPERIMENTAL_receipt` method like this

```
{
  "jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": "2",
  "method": "EXPERIMENTAL_receipt",
  "params": {"receipt_id": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"}
}
```

yet the node returns error indicating, that there is no receipt with given ID

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "name": "HANDLER_ERROR",
        "cause": {
            "name": "UNKNOWN_RECEIPT",
            "info": {
                "receipt_id": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
            }
        },
        "code": -32000,
        "message": "Server error",
        "data": {
            "name": "UNKNOWN_RECEIPT",
            "info": {
                "receipt_id": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
            }
        }
    },
    "id": "2"
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TL;DR the receipt is a **local receipt**

---

The transaction from your example is a simple `AddKey` action where the sender is the receiver (remember this, it's important)

1. "Execute" transaction (means to convert the transaction into a Receipt)
2. Apply the Receipts

As the result of the conversion of the transaction into a receipt is your `transaction_outcome`

```
"outcome": {
  "receipt_ids": [
    "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
  ],
  "status": {
    "SuccessReceiptId": "JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ"
  },
```

This receipt is about to be applied and the `predecessor_id` and the `receiver_id` are equal. In `nearcore` such receipts are called **local receipts** (sir - sender-is-receiver) and those receipts are not stored in the `nearcore` database.

[We emulate them on NEAR Indexer Framework side](https://github.com/near/nearcore/blob/808d9343db79919911f87b332b0fbea0926b7f49/chain/indexer/src/streamer/mod.rs#L107-L116) (that's why you can see Receipt  `JDnBrxh6L9KFgVUEg6U8d39rEUEmbvLQ5tZQUmJTMyFJ` on the transaction details page on NEAR Explorer)

And because `nearcore` doesn't store such receipts in the database you got `UNKNOWN_RECEIPT` from the RPC.

Comment: Thanks, that explains a lot!